# I can't get cascade to work on an entity,Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a entity that has two Many-To-One relationships, and one of them cascades on save just fine and the other one returns:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an 
unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing : dto.publicSchema.Pessoas
```

Here is the code of the entity that works:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="`Doc_tipo`", schema="public")
public class Doc_tipo implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1859372890916956036L;

@Id
@Column(nullable=false)
private int tp_doc;
@Column(nullable=false,columnDefinition="CHAR(255)")
private String descricao;
@Column(nullable=false,columnDefinition="CHAR(255)")
private String tp_emissor;

//getters and setters
}
```

And here is the code of the entity that will not allow cascade:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="`Pessoas`", schema="public")
public class Pessoas implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 8292302132119274975L;

@Id @GeneratedValue
@Column(nullable=false,columnDefinition="serial NOT NULL")
private int seq_pessoa;


static Date padrao_dt_criacao = new Date();
@Column(nullable=false, columnDefinition="date NOT NULL")
private Date dt_criacao = padrao_dt_criacao;

@Column(columnDefinition="CHAR(255)")
private String nome;

@Column(columnDefinition="CHAR(1) NULL")
private char tp_pessoa;

@Column(columnDefinition="CHAR(255)")
private String fantasia;

@Column(columnDefinition="VARCHAR(25)")
private String idioma;

@Column(columnDefinition="VARCHAR(25)")
private String login;

@Column(columnDefinition="VARCHAR(25)")
private String senha;   


static Date padrao_dt_i = new Date();
@Column(nullable=false, columnDefinition="date NOT NULL")
private Date dt_i = padrao_dt_i;

//Pessoa está ativa para o sitema se este campo estiver em branco
@Column(columnDefinition="date")
private Date dt_f; 

@Column(columnDefinition="oid")
private int foto;   

//getters and setters   
}
```

And here is the class that has relationships Many-To-One with the two above
but cascade will only work on the first one:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="`Documentos`", schema="public")
public class Documentos implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -4874330647877687810L;

@Id
@ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="seq_pessoa",columnDefinition="integer",referencedColumnName="seq_pessoa",nullable=false)
private Pessoas seq_pessoa;

@Id @GeneratedValue
@Column(nullable=false,columnDefinition="serial NOT NULL")
private int cd_doc;

@ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="tp_doc",referencedColumnName="tp_doc",nullable=false)
private Doc_tipo tp_doc;

@Column(nullable=false)
private int tp_emissor;

@Column(nullable=false,columnDefinition="CHAR(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'DF'::bpchar")
private String tp_emissor_uf="DF";

@Column(columnDefinition="CHAR(5)")
private String alfa_doc;

@Column(nullable=false,columnDefinition="CHAR(20)")
private String nr_doc;

//Data de validade do documento
@Column(columnDefinition="date")
private Date dt_f_valid;

@Transient
transient static Date padrao_dt_i = new Date();
@Column(columnDefinition="date DEFAULT now()")
private Date dt_i = padrao_dt_i;

@Column(columnDefinition="date")
private Date dt_f;
    //getters and setters
}
```

When I go to save a Documentos object hibernate inserts the Doc_tipo in to its table
as its supposed to, and instead of inserting the Pessoa object as well throws me that exception.

Here is the class that manipulates the session(it's just for tests):

```
public class Hibernate {



public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {

    SessionFactory sessionFactory = null;
    try {
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();

        configuration.configure();

        ServiceRegistry  serviceRegistry = new  ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(

        configuration.getProperties()).buildServiceRegistry();

        sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
    } catch (HibernateException hbe) {

        hbe.printStackTrace();

    }

    return sessionFactory;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {


    SessionFactory sessionFactory = getSessionFactory();
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();


    Pessoas a = new Pessoas();
    a.setDt_criacao(new Date());
    a.setDt_f(new Date());
    a.setDt_i(new Date());
    a.setFantasia("teste");
    a.setFoto(12);
    a.setIdioma("aa");
    a.setLogin("aa");
    a.setNome("aa");
    a.setSenha("a");
    a.setTp_pessoa('H');



    Doc_tipo b = new Doc_tipo();
    b.setDescricao("aa");
    b.setTp_doc(5);
    b.setTp_emissor("aaa");


    Documentos c = new Documentos();

    c.setAlfa_doc("aaa");
    c.setDt_f(new Date());
    c.setDt_f_valid(new Date());
    c.setDt_i(new Date());
    c.setNr_doc("aa");
    c.setSeq_pessoa(a);
    c.setTp_doc(b);
    c.setTp_emissor(1);
    c.setTp_emissor_uf("aa");

    //session.save(a);
    session.save(c);





    session.getTransaction().commit();
    session.close();



}

}
```

If i remove the comment on the save() Pessoas object, everything works fine, but i shouldn't have to do that, the same exception happens when i try to cascade save in another
entity that has a Many-To-One relationship with Pessoas too.

Comment: did you override hashCode() and equal() properly?

Comment: Does this even compile? You're missing closing quotes on your `columnDefinition` attributes for `dt_criacao` and `dt_i`. Also, you don't need to mark your static fields as transient (I doubt this is the issue, but it feels weird)

Comment: Yes it does, those are just part of the code i removed because i could'nt format it right,and forgot to fix, it's my first question here.

Comment: By the way, use "@username" when replying to someone's comment or else they won't be notified of your response (click the "help" link by the comment box for more info). It might help to show us how you're saving the entities, because at first glance, the definitions seem fine.

Comment: @DannyMo there you go, added it.

Comment: @rokonoid i did generate hashcode and equals on eclipse and tested, nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

Documentos references Pessoas with primary key (Pessoas.seq_pessoa) which is only created after it has been saved/flushed to database as Pessoas uses serial. So there is nothing to reference with before save/persist actually happens.

Also, you shouldn't use multiple @Id annotations to define composite identity unless you are also defining @IdClass that holds aforementioned @Id fields. Or you could you @EmbeddedId annotation as well. JPA supports two different approaches for compound PKs. In each case there must be a PK class that includes the fields.

A) Multiple @Id fields/attributes on the entity. Names and types of fields in the entity must match those in the PK class. Must also have an @IdClass annotation on the class. Ex:

```
public class EmpPK {
int id;
String name;
...
}

@Entity
@IdClass(EmpPK.class)
public class Employee {
@Id int id;
@Id String name;

...
}
```

B) Embed an attribute of the PK class in the entity. In this case the attribute is marked with @EmbeddedId and the PK class must be annotated with @Embeddable. Ex:

```
@Embeddable
public class EmpPK {
int id;
String name;
...
}

@Entity
public class Employee {
@EmbeddedId EmpPK empId;
...
}
```